# How to draw a smooth edges circle in ios

Tags: iphone, cgcontext

Hi in my application i have to draw a circle on view. For that i used below code

```
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 2.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef,red,green,blue, 1.0);

        CGRect circlePoint = (CGRectMake(rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y,rect.size.width,rect.size.height));

        CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(contextRef, circlePoint);
```

i am getting the circle also but i am getting the circle in this manner[image: if you observer the image the thickness of the line is not uniform but i need the circle with uniform line thickness]

if any one have any idea please let me know. Thanks in advance please help.

Comment: Basically, you're drawing outside the context, so it is being clipped. A two pixel stroke is half outside the rect when it is drawn.

Comment: Hi jrturton please help me, how to draw a circle indside the context inorder to avoid clipping.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you follow the duplicate link? The answer is there, that's why I linked it.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. I found the place and issue is resolved.

Comment: Hi one more doubt can we access these circle properties from someone else.I mean now i added circle on view successfully. Now i want to change the thickness of the line with button click means 2 to 4 and in the same way from 4 to 2 using another button is it possible.